# How do I prevent my trackpad from accidentally double-clicking?

Tags: windows, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

I own a Lenovo Yoga 900 that I bought last year. Ever since I received it, I disliked the trackpad because of it's inaccuracy. More specifically, what really annoys me about it is that whenever I try to click by placing my finger on the trackpad and applying pressure until it physically "clicks" down, the laptop *sometimes* registers it as two immediate clicks at once. For most UI elements, this gets extremely frustrating.

I have disabled tap-to-click and have played with the plam reject and sensitivity settings to see if there is anything I can do. Sadly, nothing has helped. To make the laptop more comfortable to use, I have changed one registry key to make the entire trackpad surface primary click, but this issue still persists without this key changed. I thought this problem originally stemmed from a bad install of Windows, but after a fresh install, the machine still does not click properly sometimes.

What do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: Part of your problem may be trying to use the trackpad in a way that it's not designed for.  The trackpads typically aren't pressure-sensitive. they just detect the presence of your finger.  If they are too sensitive, they can detect your hand when it is simply close (that's the reason for the palm reject setting).  It sounds like you have tried to set everything to be extremely insensitive, and then want to rely on pressure.  That will be unreliable, and may be why you are getting unintended results (and you may eventually damage it).  (cont'd)

Comment: If you want to simulate mouse clicks, you need the tap-to-click feature.  If the pad is overly sensitive, stay aware of where your hands are and keep them away from the pad when you aren't using it.  Sometimes the built-in pads just suck and the only solution is to disable it and use an external pointing device.

Comment: This trackpad has a physical click. I'm not talking about pressure activated clicking. The setting I leave the mousepad at is more sensitive than not in order to prevent it from ignoring my finger swiping.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm what the "click" is.  I've never seen a touchpad where the pad, itself, is designed to move to activate a switch.  But I've seen damaged touchpads that made a clicking sound if pressed.  Is that a feature described in the user manual (or is the click just a system sound generated through the speaker)?

Comment: The whole trackpad is a button. [Here is a demonstration video of a similar trackpad.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkSFrCmEdOQ) The click of the button is an actual hardware click, not an emulated click from the system's speakers. The demonstration videos in the Synaptics software settings demonstrates that the pad can be clicked anywhere. These types of trackpad became very popular ever since Apple started making them in their Macbooks over 6 years ago.

Comment: Not being a Macbook user (and apparently a user of only old or low end laptops), I finally get to see how the other half lives.  :-)

Comment: I've been having this exact same issue, but on a Sony VAIO.  Can't seem to find anything that helps